# Allow only one slide toggle div to show at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I am working on a site where I have 4 expandable divs using jquery's slide toggle. All works fine but I don't want more than 1 of those divs expanded at a time. In other words: when a div is expanded, other divs that are expanded should close. Accordion isn't an option I think because all the div's styling is different. Below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// slidetoggles

    $("#tgx-window").hide();
        $("#tgx-button").show();
        $("#tgs-window").hide();
        $("#tgs-button").show();
        $("#tgm-window").hide();
        $("#tgm-button").show();
        $("#tgl-window").hide();
        $("#tgl-button").show();

    $('#tgx-button').click(function(){
    $('#tgx-button').toggleClass('closebutton');
    $("#tgx-window").slideToggle();
    });

    $('#tgs-button').click(function(){
    $('#tgs-button').toggleClass('closebutton');
    $("#tgs-window").slideToggle();
    });

    $('#tgm-button').click(function(){
    $('#tgm-button').toggleClass('closebutton');
    $("#tgm-window").slideToggle();
    });

    $('#tgl-button').click(function(){
    $('#tgl-button').toggleClass('closebutton');
    $("#tgl-window").slideToggle();
    });
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="" class="show_hide" id="<?=strtolower($service['title']);?>-button"></a>
        <div class="slidingDiv" id="<?=strtolower($service['title']);?>-window">
            <?
            $infoBox = '<h1>'.$service['subtitel'].'</h1>';
            $infoBox .= $service['description'];
            echo replaceTags($infoBox);
            ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: post your html codes too

Comment: Maybe you can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your current code?

Comment: you can use accordion control .

Comment: @Ravi Except he said he didn't want to ;)

Comment: @Mario ok. i deleted my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick commenting :) I'll post the HTML code too. I dont't have time to creat jsfiddle right now, but maybe i'll create one later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer this question without knowing your HTML but here is a solution I hope;

**HTML (I presume):**

```
<div id="tgx-window">tgx window</div>
<div id="tgs-window">tgs window</div>
<div id="tgm-window">tgm window</div>
<div id="tgl-window">tgl window</div>

<button id="tgx-button">Show tgx</button>
<button id="tgs-button">Show tgs</button>
<button id="tgm-button">Show tgm</button>
<button id="tgl-button">Show tgl</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $windows = $('#tgx-window,#tgs-window,#tgm-window,#tgl-window'),
        $buttons = $('#tgx-button,#tgs-button,#tgm-button,#tgl-button');
    $windows.hide();

    $buttons.on('click', function(e) {
        var $id;
        e.preventDefault();
        $buttons.removeClass('closebutton');
        $id = $('#' + this.id.split('-')[0] + '-window');// Get window id
        $windows.slideUp();
        if(! $id.is(':visible') ) {
            $id.slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('closebutton');
        }
    });
});
```

You can see a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/62NPt/4/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution! :) Only problem left is that this messes up the toggle class. The button of the div that is closed by opening another div keeps it's toggle class.

Comment: Ok. Updated my answer. Now it's `.closebutton` aware and it toggles open window beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` instead of `id` of button and probably its parent `.tgx-window`

```
$('.tgx-button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('closebutton');
    $(this).closest(".tgx-window").slideToggle();
});
```